# How can I send the serve response data from a fetch API to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, client-server, fetch-api

Having a json object,I made an API call using fetch API and I got a response with the expected resuts. How can I send the results to the client, so as to be able to display them in the interface? I used express module from Node.js.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
res.sendStatus(200);



jsonBody = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./resources/jsonBody.json", {
    encoding: 'utf8'
}));



function results() {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(jsonBody),
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + predictionKey,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(response => 
                 console.log(response.Results.output1.value.Values));


}

results()


})


});
```

The client side post function:

```
function postMessage(message){
  $.post("http://localhost:8000",message);
}
```

This is the response of the api call on the server

```
[ [ '1008', '0', '1' ],
  [ '1079', '1', '3' ],
  [ '1022', '2', '3' ] ]
```

and I want to display these values in the interface (on client)

Comment: Can you add more details about the client? What type of client it is? What do you mean by displaying values on the interface?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable url used in the fetch is not defined anywhere, so I have to assume you have a global variable elsewhere to the API you are calling.

If so, then you are doing this out of sequence - you are sending an empty 200 OK then fetching the jsonBody (which is another global var, maybe unintentionally) but then never using those results.

Try rearranging like so:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);

  var jsonBody = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./resources/jsonBody.json", {
    encoding: 'utf8'
  }));

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonBody),
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + predictionKey,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(response => { 
    console.log(response.Results.output1.value.Values);
    res.json(response.Results.output1.value.Values); // or whatever you want from response
  });
});
```